# Rails: to_json method, add a function return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model User. User contain :name and :second_name fields. I define function in model

```
def full_name
    self.name + ' ' + self.second_name
end
```

When I call to_json() method on user object i get {name: '...', second_name: '...'}. How I add to result full_name field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about defining `as_json` method in your User model and overriding the default behaviour of to_json.

So this will become:

```
def as_json(options)
  super(:methods => [:full_name])
end
```

For reference also see: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Comment: As Bryan notes, this is clean and allows you to call multiple class methods.  Additionally you can also exclude items that are unnecessary by adding `except` in your options

Answer (score 1):

Override `.as_json` in your User model, add following lines to your user model:

```
def as_json(options)
  super.merge({
      full_name: "#{self.name} #{self.second_name}"
  })
end
```

And in your controller, just write: `render @user`, don't explicit call `.to_json`